# Issues Logging into Site

Tags: python, forms, authentication, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a small script which logs into a webpage and then from there I can do other things.

I have no issue getting un-authenticated pages, but when I try "login", It doesn't seem to be posting the page. I am not sure if it is an issue that there is no form action, and there is also another hidden form on this page.

When I try my code, the html which comes back has the fields filled out with the user/pass I have supplied. It is as if the "Log In" button hasn't been pressed.

**Here's the form:**

```
<form method="POST">
   <table border=1  bgcolor="#a7a7a7"  style="border-collapse:collapse;border-style:solid; border-color:#006600" >
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table  cellspacing=2 cellpadding=4>
               <tr>
                  <td align="right"  bgcolor="#b7b7b7" >your email</td>
                  <td  bgcolor="#c7c7c7" ><input name="user_email" type="text" size=30 value=""><br></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td align="right"  bgcolor="#b7b7b7" >your password</td>
                  <td  bgcolor="#c7c7c7" ><input name="user_password" type="password" size=30><br></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" colspan=2><input type="submit" name="do_login" value="log in"></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" name="allhidden[0]" value="dummy">
   <input type="hidden" name="allhidden[_ga]" value="1234">
   <input type="hidden" name="allhidden[_gid]" value="1234">
   <input type="hidden" name="allhidden[gd_session]" value="eFmcHb">
   <input type="hidden" name="allhidden[grey_cookie]" value="&&&">
   <br>
</form>
```

**Here's my code:**

```py
s = requests.Session()

# Perform login
result = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data={
    "user_email": USERNAME, 
    "user_password": PASSWORD, 
})

# Scrape url
html = s.get(DASHBOARD_URL).content
print(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Tried variations of code, but know the above works on normal pages. Is there something else I need to pass or to initiate the submit button?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you checked what is returned in`result`? Look into it to figure out if login was successful. The content there may also be helpful to understand what is wrong.

Comment: In order to emulate the behavior of the browser you need to pass all form fields including `hidden` fields. Specifically the names like `gd_session` and `grey_cookie` suggest that some sort of session is already established.

Comment: could you provide `LOGIN_URL`

Comment: So I tried the result and I get a 200. 

The URL I am trying to log into is greyhound-data.com/login.htm

Comment: So I tried to post all the hidden values too but unable to get past the login page. The Html which is returned is the login page again, while getting a 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting<sup>[1]</sup> the request, you can see that the following fields are required:

```
z: 7T2RlN
user_email: USERNAME
user_password: PASSWORD
do_login: log in
allhidden[0]: dummy
```

You need to scrape the value of `z` first from http://greyhound-data.com/login.htm, which is a hidden field value: `<input type="hidden" name="z" value="7T2RlN">`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('http://greyhound-data.com/login.htm')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    z = soup.find('input', {'name': 'z'})['value']
    data = {
        'z': z,
        'user_email': USERNAME,
        'user_password': PASSWORD,
        'do_login': 'log in',
        'allhidden[0]': 'dummy',
    }
    r = s.post('http://greyhound-data.com/login.htm', data=data)
    print('You are now successfully logged in.' in r.text)
    # True
```

[1]: To inspect the request:

1. Open Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
2. Click on Network
3. Enter login details and submit the form
4. Click on `login.htm`

---

**Updated code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('http://greyhound-data.com/login.htm')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    data = {
        'user_email': USERNAME,
        'user_password': PASSWORD,
        'do_login': 'log in',
    }

    for hidden_field in soup.find_all('input', type='hidden', value=True):
        data[hidden_field['name']] = hidden_field['value']

    r = s.post('http://greyhound-data.com/login.htm', data=data)
    print('You are now successfully logged in.' in r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! The only issue is that it has worked just once, now I get this error:

python grey.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grey.py", line 55, in <module>
    listLinks()
  File "grey.py", line 19, in listLinks
    z = soup.find('input', {'name': 'z'})['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Is there some caching happening?

I did try manually set z too, but it didn't seem to help..

Comment: Nope, I have used the code and still getting the same error. One thing I have noticed is that even when I view the page source for login.htm the value for z is not always there